# Zabbix dependcies unmet

Tags: dependencies, debian, zabbix

I want to upgrade a Zabbix 2.2.7 to a 3.4 but there is a problem when I want to install zabbix-server:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zabbix-server-mysql : 
Depends: libmariadbclient18 (>= 5.5.36) but it is not installable

Depends: libsnmp30 (>= 5.7.3+dfsg-1.7~dfsg) but 5.7.2.1+dfsg-1 is to be installed

Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

libbssl1.1 and libmariadbclients are not avaialable, however I updated my repositories with apt-get update and apt-get upgrade.

And I don't know for libsnmp how to remove it and then install the new one.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced this Issues and i fixed it

need to install the dependencies **libsnmp30**

```
#apt-get install libsnmp30
#sudo apt-get -f install
#sudo apt-get install zabbix-agent
```

It works fine.....

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with installing zabbix-proxy-mysql.

For me helped that: once again set repo as described on [official zabbix doc](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/installation/install_from_packages/repository_installation) page

```
# wget http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.0/debian/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_3.0-2+stretch_all.deb
# dpkg -i zabbix-release_3.0-2+stretch_all.deb
# apt-get update
```

Comment: Please include the essentials of the solution directly in your answer, rather than just posting a link, otherwise the answer becomes useless when the link dies. Did it for you this time.